# Display Ajax response in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I looked over tens of similar questions but I couldn't find the solution I needed. Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate. I want to show the Ajax response in the page, once the window is loaded.

## Code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="rate-ul">
    <li id="LTL">LTL Freight</li>
</ul>
```

and the jquery part to change it is:

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
if(condition){
$("#LTL").change(UpdateLTLRating);
}
function UpdateLTLRating() {
    console.log("update shipping called");
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        data: 'call=ajax&method=ltlRateList&'
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp)
        $(".rate-ul").html(resp);
        },
         error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        }
    });
```

I get the update shipping called in the console, but I don't get `resp` called on the windows load. When I attach it to a button click event, I get the `resp` in the console as well. I haven't been able to get `resp` on the page.

Comment: You mention "window load", but all your logic is showing in regards to when the method is called, is the change event.  So from what you are showing, this method would not be called on window load.

Comment: @Taplar is right—you have no logic set up for triggering the function when the window loads. Either call `UpdateLTLRating` directly: `UpdateLTLRating()`, or trigger a change event on your element: `$('#LTL').trigger('change')`.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample, it's not clear that you're even calling your function on window load to get the data you want, if this is the case in your original code, here's how you can do it:

```
if(condition){
    $("#LTL").change(UpdateLTLRating);
}
function UpdateLTLRating() {
    console.log("update shipping called");
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        data: 'call=ajax&method=ltlRateList&'
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp)
        $(".rate-ul").html(resp);
        },
         error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    UpdateLTLRating();
});
```